# how to set margins in A3 page when using the KOMAoptions command inside an A4 document

Tags: koma-script, geometry

I am inserting an A3 page in an A4 document using the **KOMAoptions** command:

```
\afterpage{ % Insert after the current page
\clearpage

\KOMAoptions{paper=a3}
\recalctypearea
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{business-schema.png}
    \caption{\texttt{vo business} schema tables}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
}
```

However I'm totally at a loss when trying to change (reduce) the margins on that A3 page. I tried using \newgeometry commands but they changed the size back to A4. Currently the margins I get are too wide, both horizontally and vertically:

[image]

Comment: in what way does this question differ from the previous two? Don't just keep asking the same question, if a specific part of an answer isn't clear you can ask a new question on that point referring to the previous answer. Also please always post _complete_ documents so that people can reproduce the problem (use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` so `\includegraphics` just makes a rectangle and the image isn't needed to demonstrate the effect.

Comment: The previous questions were about adding an A3 page, this one is about changing the margins on that page (once an A3 page has been successfully answered). It seemed to me sufficiently different to justify a new post. Your point on complete documents is taken.

Comment: There isn't really any difference that I can see, you want a text block of a certain size, whether you think of it as an a4 page with negative margins or an A3 page with small margins or an A0 page with big margins doesn't make much difference to TeX (you might want to put slightly different directives to a pdf viewer in how to adjust the page view but it makes no difference at all to the typesetting.)

Comment: Shame on Caesar's assassin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By trial and error I've discovered that I can use **\addtolength** to reduce the margin for the A3 page so as to accommodate a wide graphic set at 1.35 of the textwidth

```
\afterpage{ % Insert after the current page
\clearpage

\KOMAoptions{paper=a3}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-2.0cm}
\recalctypearea
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.35\textwidth]{}
    \caption{\texttt{vo\ business} schema tables}
    \label{fig:vo-business-schema}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
}
\restoregeometry
```

Comment: If it's just for that.. I think you could use the `addmargin` environment.